# SQL union, разные типы данных. Почему это работает?

Tags: sql, объединение

Есть такой запрос -

```
SELECT OrderID 
FROM [Orders] 
    UNION
SELECT EmployeeID * 100 
FROM Employees 
    UNION 
SELECT ProductName
FROM Products
```

И он вполне себе работает, несмотря на разные типы данных, почему ?
[Таблица Orders](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all)

Comment: Значит СУБД умеет приводить типы в таких случаях к общему знаменателю, думаю к строке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**для MS SQL так:**

Если оператор связывает два выражения различных типов данных, то по правилам приоритета типов данных определяется, какой тип данных имеет больший приоритет и будет преобразован в тип данных с меньшим приоритетом. Если неявное преобразование не поддерживается, возвращается ошибка.

В вашем случае **INT** преобразуется в **VARCHAR** / **NVARCHAR**, проверить можно создав представление с вашим запросом.

Подробнее о приоритетах: [Data type precedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Статья с хорошим примером: [Data Type Precedence and Implicit Conversions](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/never_say_never/2010/02/21/data-type-precedence-and-implicit-conversions/).

Comment: Integer выше по приоритету, разве нет ?

Comment: наверное все таки приводится к типу данных с __меньшим__ приоритетом: INT --> VARCHAR

Comment: @MaxU да, вы правы. В статье ошибка.

Comment: какой тип данных имеет **меньший** --> _больший_ ?   приоритет и будет преобразован в тип данных с меньшим приоритетом.

Comment: @Haart **больший** -> **меньший** (int -> varchar)

Comment: Это я понял, я написал то что написано в ответе было, вы уже поправили. Спасибо.